# Setting baseurl in cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp

I am working on an application which is running in CakePHP and I am using AJAX queries from within.

In all the cases for all the ajax post i have used the url as

```
var ht = $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "http://172.20.52.99/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/viewChoices/"+attribute_id,
                     async: false
                }).responseText;
var myObject = eval('(' + ht + ')');
```

Is there any way in CakePHP where I can give my base URL as `http://172.20.52.99/FormBuilder/index.php/` and to call the base URL in all the places I want.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing following code

```
'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->base
```

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`----it will give you working host

and `$this->base`---will give you working url

Answer (score 2):

You can use $this->base to get base url.

Comment: For me this just prints out /sitename

Answer (score 2):

you may use

```
<?php echo Router::fullbaseUrl();?>
```

as well.

Refer http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could set default URL for all your ajax requests that way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: 'http://172.20.52.99/FormBuilder/index.php/'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any one method of following

1. `<?php echo $this->Html->url('/');?>`
2. `<?php Router::url('/', true); ?>`
3. `<?php echo $this->base;?>`
4. `<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>`
5. Define constant in Config/core.php as `define("BASE_URL", "www.yoursite.com/");` and use `BASE_URL` anywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

I assume I've the same scenario: for development, the site is available at localhost/cake, whereby in production the site is deployed in the root dir of example.com. In the header I set:

`<base href="<?php echo $base_url ?>" />`,

in `AppContoller::beforeRender()` I set:

`$this->set('base_url', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].Router::url('/'));`.

This works fine for everything, except JS (so thus AJAX), as it ignores base_url.

Therefore I have a workaround (uses jQuery, but easy to substitute without):

```
forUrl = function(url) {
    return $('base').attr('href')+url.substr(1);
}

login = function() {
    $.post(forUrl('/ajax/profileDiv'), $('#profile-login-form').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            (...)
        });
}
```

Comment: Your first three lines of code do nothing for me. $base_url is undefined.

Comment: It is set by $this->set('base_url', ...). Where do you have that in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This might also be helpful:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1448/url

```
<?php echo $this->Html->url('/posts', true); ?>

//Output
http://somedomain.com/posts
```